# Given that $f(x)g'(x)-f'(x)g(x) \neq 0$, show that if $f(x)$ has two zeros, $g(x)$ has a zero between them

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The original question is:

> The function $f$ and $g$ satisfy
> $$f(x)g'(x)-f'(x)g(x)\neq0$$ for all $x$.
>
> If $f(x)=0$ has only two zeros which are $\alpha$ and $\beta$, show that the only zero of $g(x)=0$ exists between $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

I made my procedure, but I think the solution should be more strict, since, for instance, the part that I used limits. This part, I have some difficulties to show why the limits should have the following value, precisely. Which part I have to modify to eliminate such an intuition?

My procedure:

> Let $f(x)=k(x-\alpha)(x-\beta), \space \space g(x)=l(x-\gamma)$, $h(x)=\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$
>
> Note that $$h'(x)= \frac{f(x)g'(x)-f'(x)g(x)}{\{g(x)\}^2} \neq0$$
>
> W.L.O.G:  $\space\space k, l\gt0$
>
> If $\gamma\lt \alpha, \beta$, $$\lim_{x\to\alpha+}h(x)=-\infty$$ and $$  \lim_{x\to\beta-}h(x)=-\infty$$
>
> There exist $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ such that $h(\alpha+\delta_1)=h(\beta-\delta_2)$.
>
> By MVT, there $\exists c \in (\alpha+\delta_1, \beta-\delta_2)$ such that $h'(c)=0$
>
> Contradiction! I.s.w. for $\gamma \gt \alpha, \beta$.

Also, I think there exist some more clear solutions. Could you please suggest me some ideas about this question? Thanks!

Comment: It does not follow that $f(x)=k(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$, unless you know that $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: @lhf Ah right, that was the biggest problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't follow that $g$ has only $1$ zero. For example, consider the functions $f(x)=x^2-1$ and $g(x)=x^2-5x$ defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $f(x)g'(x)-f'(x)g(x)=5x^2-2x+5\ne 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ because the quadratic has a negative discriminant. $f$ has exactly $2$ zeros: $\pm 1$. However, $g$ also has $2$ zeros: $0$ and $5$.

You can, instead, show that $g$ has exactly one zero that lies between $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Assume w.l.o.g. that $\alpha < \beta$ and define the function $h$ for $x\ne \alpha,\beta$ as you defined it. Suppose that there exist $x<y$ in the interval $(\alpha,\beta)$ such that $h(x)=h(y)$. Applying the mean value theorem for $[x,y]$, there is a $c\in(x,y)$ such that $h'(c)=0$, a contradiction. So $h$ is injective in $(\alpha,\beta)$ which means it has no more than $1$ zero there. Next, note that $g(\alpha)\ne 0$ and $g(\beta)\ne 0$ and $f$ has a constant sign in $(\alpha,\beta)$ since it has no zeros in that interval. Hence, $\lim_{x\to\alpha^+}1/f(x)=+\infty$ or $-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\alpha^+}g(x)=g(\alpha)\ne 0$. Multiplying the two limits gives us $\lim_{x\to\alpha^+}h(x)=+\infty$ or $-\infty$. And similarly $\lim_{x\to\beta^-}h(x)=+\infty$ or $-\infty$. However, $h$ is injective in $(\alpha,\beta)$ so the $2$ infinite limits need to have different signs. So there are numbers $a,b\in(\alpha,\beta)$ such that $h(a)<0$ and $h(b)>0$ and $h$ has a zero in the interval.

Comment: There are lots of things I have to learn carefully. Thanks for giving the clear proof!

Comment: @bjorn93  Something funny is going on if I let $h=\frac{f}{g}$. By the same reasoning, $h$ is obviously injective, but in this case, $h(\alpha)=h(\beta)=0$. What went wrong?